# What is @$ in perl?

Tags: perl, exception, sigils

I came across this, expecting it to be a typo for `$@`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

eval {
  my $error = Not::Here->new();
};

warn @$;
```

And to my surprise it outputs this:

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "Not::Here" (perhaps you forgot to load "Not::Here"?) at dollar_array.pl line 6.
>       ...caught at dollar_array.pl line 9.

I'm unable to find any information about `@$`, and it's not listed on [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), nor in [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

Since the output show `caught at ...`, it seems that this is something in the exception handling of perl.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@$` has no meaning (yet) in Perl. It exists because `$$` exists (for each special variable "sigil-char", all other "another_sigil-char" variables exist). Therefore, `warn` gets no arguments - you can verify that by using just `warn;` - you'll get the same output.

Now, let's read the documentation for [warn](http://p3rl.org/warn):

> If the output is empty and `$@` already contains a value (typically from a previous eval) that value is used after appending `"\t...caught"` to `$@`. This is useful for staying almost, but not entirely similar to `die`.

`$@` contains the exception from the `eval`, so the behaviour is expected.